# Dell Precision 5510 Boot Partition Deleted?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted, boot-repair

While wanting to format my SD-card of 4gigs I accidentally removed a 4gig partition on my main drive in GParted.
The system obviously wouldn't boot anymore.
Not even showing Grub.

I tried the *Recommanded Repair* from [Boot-Repair-Disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/), but it almost fails immediately with:

> GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.

Since I already proved myself as an expert on Gparted I came here looking for some answers or guidance. 
I have a 512gig NVME SSD in RAID0 if that helps.
Also this laptop came with Ubuntu 14.04 pre-installed.

I'll also attach a link to my BootInfo [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26272258/)

Thanks in advance.

Tim

Comment: you're booting in legacy mode, you need to boot in EFI mode.

Comment: Hmm weird in my BIOS under Secure Boot. I have the secure boot enabled which states. `For secure boot to be enabled. The system needs to be in UEFI mode.` and it is `enabled` it says. Am I missing something?

Comment: is Legacy CSM also enabled? a grub bios partition is only needed for Legacy boot.

Comment: Hmm @ravery can't seem to find anything close to that option in my BIOS?
I have categories: General, System Config, Video, Security, Secure Boot, Performance, Power Manag, POST behavior,  Virtualization Support, Wireless, Maintenance, System Logs and SupportAssist System Resolution.
Any idea where I could find that option?

Comment: it should be with your boot options, possibly you can not turn it off. Some systems will drop to Legacy mode if a boot loader is found in the MBR of the boot disk. Usually you can turn CSM off in BIOS to force a EFI boot. Or possibly boot repair is assuming legacy because there isn't an EFI system partition.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. Under General > Advanced Boot Options I have 3 options all of which are disabled.
Enabled Legacy Option ROMs,  
Enabled UEFI Network Stack,  
Enable Attempt Legacy Boot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70903/discussion-between-tim-and-ravery).

Comment: You might try Disabling "Attempt Legacy Boot" and running Boot repair again.